# Sub Query using WITH Clause

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table where messages are stored as they happen. Usually there is a message 'A' and sometimes the A's are separated by a single message 'B'. Now I want to group the values so I'm able to analyze them, for example finding longest 'A'-streak or distribution of 'A'-streaks.The query is written in impala.

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT Messages.Message, Timestamp, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Message ORDER BY Timestamp) AS gn,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rn
FROM Messages
), cte2 AS (
SELECT Message, Timestamp, gn, rn, gn - rn  as gb
FROM cte 
), cte3 AS (
SELECT Message, MIN(Timestamp) As Ts, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Message, gb)
SELECT Message, Cnt FROM cte3
ORDER BY Ts
```

but when I am using the below code it is giving zero sum.

```
select Message, sum(Cnt ) from (
WITH cte as (
SELECT Messages.Message, Timestamp, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Message ORDER BY Timestamp) AS gn,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rn
FROM Messages
), cte2 AS (
SELECT Message, Timestamp, gn, rn, gn - rn  as gb
FROM cte 
), cte3 AS (
SELECT Message, MIN(Timestamp) As Ts, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Message, gb)
SELECT Message, Cnt FROM cte3
ORDER BY Ts) 
group by Message
```

Even If I put the above code in another select statement, it giving the count as zero .

```
select * from (WITH cte as (
SELECT Messages.Message, Timestamp, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Message ORDER BY Timestamp) AS gn,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rn
FROM Messages
), cte2 AS (
SELECT Message, Timestamp, gn, rn, gn - rn  as gb
FROM cte 
), cte3 AS (
SELECT Message, MIN(Timestamp) As Ts, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Message, gb)
SELECT Message, Cnt FROM cte3
ORDER BY Ts ) aa where message='A'
```

Can you please help me to find out what's the issue here.

Comment: Are you getting an error or a zero sum?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  - Zero sum